# Should we limit Community's bumps?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A [4 year-old thread](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1393/50076) expressed this sentiment; are we still on-board? A user under my [Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354709/612423) suggested we can **ask** for this by tagging `support` (also `featured`, which mods here can do).

Personally I'm in favor for reasons described in the linked threads. In the meantime, there is a [workaround](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1708/50076).

[Updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354709/612423) my Meta SE post.

Answer (score 2):

That’s not a workaround. That is what we all should be doing anyway. Voting is what this site is built around. People on DSP don’t vote enough. There are way too many good answers with 0 votes (which is the reason Community bumps these posts). [I have written about this before here on Meta](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1593/33605). Vote often and vote hard. Don’t give Community anything to bump!

Interestingly enough, I came across this post because Community bumped it...

Comment: +1 _"People on DSP don't vote enough"_. There are some [valid reasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1jMH.png). Regardless I'll testify to this being a positive feedback loop where the regulars don't vote on each others' posts, despite none of the reasons applying.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon: Indeed, some questions are just “bla”, not good, not closable, not interesting enough to answer. What to do with those?

Comment: Unsure. Often I'll read by author-first and skip anything with "modified by Community". The problem diminishes with enough user activity, but I still think a general solution is to hard-limit the number of concurrent bumps on the front page. If others are like me, such bumps are self-defeating.

Comment: [Related](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1789/50076)

Answer (score 0):

You might have noticed that they didn't like that I put a bounty on your question.

[image]

Comment: I did, and I'm inclined to agree putting that message in the bounty was a bit much - and you should _probably_ remove this or they may take worse action. Not worth taking a hit to barely prove a point.

Comment: And you bountied my post but didn't upvote this Q&A - bit strange; my request holds more water if I can show them this network's users support the initiative _now_, not 4 years ago.

Comment: so what are they gonna do?  come to my home and harm my family?

Comment: Surely not, but you put much effort into the 14k rep that none of us rather see something happen to.

Comment: i never saw this post before today. but i did see your post in the meta.se and i **did** upvote that.  want me to screenshoot it?

Comment: fuck the rep.  so what?

Comment: i don't hang around the meta pages much.  last time was when whats-his-name posted his dreadful thing about units.

Comment: Alright, nvm @ upvote. Well on rep, to each their own I suppose, but at least I think the answers stay even if the user's account is deleted, though I for one would mind not having any of my answers credited to me any longer.

Comment: well, exposing hypocrisy and exposing self-satisfied blather is something that i do, at least when they don't hold a gun to my head.

Comment: hay @PeterK do you know about this shit?

Comment: Sure, though it's not effective if shut down immediately - need to work with the system to an extent to change it. Though crafting well-written letters is fairly time consuming, and likely to get downvoted anyway when defying the meta - an excuse to spare effort, but still controlled.

Comment: So now that you've seen this thread, lighting the arrow may do good. And good luck with this post

Comment: okay, i lit it.

Comment: [_comical_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzasW.png)

Comment: is [this right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Oxh.png)

Comment: interesting @OverLordGoldDragon , you took a low-res photo from 2006 or 2007 when I was 50 and turned it into a high-res pic.  it's a little funny.  i am much more gray now.

Comment: So I guessed it right, still, I thought it's _current_, not enough boomer in comments!

Comment: Note that the DSP.SE photo is different from the photo in other SE forums.  including meta.

Comment: I know, and I like this one more for the smile. Is the other current? Looks younger than 65

Comment: Neither are real current.